# how to run an onchange function when page is loaded if the selected box is already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

Im running into a problem where i have an ajax driven page that is drawn when a user selects something from a simple drop down:

```
<select id = "selectdepartment">
    <option id = "default">Select an option...</option>
    ....
</select>
```

and the remainder of the page is drawn using the jquery `.change()` :

```
$('#selectdepartment').change(function(){

});
```

Which then runs some ajax to php script. everything works great, the problem is when i submit a form that was drawn with ajax (using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`), the data gets submited, the page reloads, and the page is cleared but the select box is still left where it was. The user has to move to a different option then back to the one the selected originally to re-fire the `.change()`. that sucks.

I could fix this by passing a php variable in all of my forms, then checking to see the variable set on every page load and if it is draw the page parts then, but this would lead to pretty messy code and it's less than desirable.

There has to be a way to do this with the jquery library, though my knowledge of the javascript language in general is not what i would like it to be. If anyone has any helpful hints please share, dont do it for me though, i wont learn that way :)

edit: code with .trigger

```
$('#selectdepartment').change(function(){
var department = $('#selectdepartment').val();
var day = $('#data').data('day');
var month = $('#data').data('month');
var year = $('#data').data('year');
//alert (department);

if(department === "Select an option..."){
    $('.hiddenuntildepartmentisselected').css({"display":"none"});
}
else{
$('.hiddenuntildepartmentisselected').css({"display":"block"});
}

showpoints(department);
drawpointstable(department, day, month, year);
displaytheuseresforselecteddepartment(department, '');

$('#sendthedepartment').val(''+department+'');
$('#hiddendepartmentidforaddinganewpoint').val(''+department+'');

}).trigger('change');//end run functions
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function to immediately trigger the `change` event handler when the page has loaded:

```
$('#selectdepartment').change(function() {
    // code here
}).trigger('change');
```

Or if you need to call it elsewhere via JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#selectdepartment').trigger('change'); // or just .change() as a shorthand
```

Comment: Did you put a console.log inside the change function to see if the trigger was getting called or not?

Comment: Im certain that this works, but now for some reason its not holding the spot it was on in the select. oh well, time to start tossing php around. thanks!

Comment: @Nick - you just type `console.log('your message')` in your code. It will then show up in the chrome developer tools console tab.

Comment: @EmmyS is it supperior to `alert()` in any way?

Comment: @Nick Yes. It's not immediately visible to the user (so less intrusive), doesn't block script execution (there's no popup to confirm), displays objects in a useful format (though it's browser dependent). The only downside is that Internet Explorer will throw an error on `console.log` statements if the Developer Tools (F12) haven't been opened.

Comment: @Nick - it's a matter of preference for the most part, although the console does allow a whole lot of things that a basic alert doesn't. The Chrome console isn't quite as full-featured as Firebug. See the Firebug API (https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Your button for the form could make use of the `onClick` attribute, which would invoke a method to parse the form fields and post the data to your php script via `.ajax()`.

In the `success` event method you then check any flags you need to and modify the element as you desire if needed.

Basic example:

Inside of `.ajax()`:

```
...

url: 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
async: true,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
data: JSON.stringify( form_fields ),
beforeSend: function()
{
     // Pre send stuff, like starting a loading gif
},
success: function( data, textStatus, xhr )
{
    // Be sure you load the page with the content first
    $( '#containing-div' ).html( data );

    // Do  your check here, and modify your element if needed here
    if( flagtocheck === 'xxx' )
    {
        // Modify the element in question...
    }

    // I call a custom method termed `.ctrls()` here that makes any 
    // adjustments to the DOM once its loaded/updated.
},
error: function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown )
{
}
```

Of course, you'll want to set `flagtocheck` appropriately in your case.

Hope that helps!

**Note regarding edit**
*This post was edited to be a little more descriptive and more easily understood. Since the person asking the question is already using the `.ajax()` method, the `success` event method is the ideal place for doing what the person asking the question is requesting.  It is 1 less method invocation to directly modify the element there than using it to call `.trigger()` or `.change()` which then also directly modifies the element.*

Comment: If they use AJAX to submit the form then there shouldn't be any need to trigger the `change` event anyway, since all of the page sections that are drawn by that would still be there. It's not a bad suggestion, but may be a non-trivial amount of work for them to do.

Comment: @anthony-grist I never suggested triggering the `CHANGE` event while already using `AJAX` to submit the form.  I suggested using `ONSUCCESS` event of the `AJAX` method to directly set the element as if .change() had been invoked.  The only difference in my answer is I did not provide another alternative for them or give them an in-depth explanation.  I don't agree with using extra events when not necessary because it is another method invocation and is less efficient and no easier to read.